# PpostgreSQL. Не находит таблицу, в чем причина?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишет, что таблицы publisher не существует. Если обращаться через **public."publisher "**, тогда распознает.

При том что с таблицей book все нормально. Хотелось бы понимать, почему программа ругается.

Comment: у pg есть настройка схем по умолчанию где искать таблицы без указанных схем. К сожалению не подскажу как называется

Comment: Но схожую таблицу он смог найти, в чем проблема с этой?

Comment: А лишний пробел в кавычках у вас тут случайно?

Comment: Нет, эта запись- следствие переноса таблицы через ЛКМ на поле ввода.

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ за вашу внимательность. я случайно, наверное, сохранил с пробелом, а парсер в скл и не думает, что пробел может быть частью строки. Переименовал и все заработало. Спасибо вам еще раз! А мне стоит учиться быть внимательнее.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в этой среде вы не сможете выбрать по умолчанию схему с которой работаете. Например в DBeaver можно, сверху когда выбрали подключение, выбрать схему по умолчанию, и тогда не нужно будет её дописывать.

Дополняю: можно в начале запроса использовать:

```
SET search_path TO "public";
```

после TO можно перечислить необходимые схемы в которых будем работать, чтобы не писать их в каждом INSERT

Answer (score 0):

Случайно, наверное, сохранил название таблицы с пробелом, а парсер и не думает, что пробел может быть частью строки. Переименовал и ошибки пропали. Стоит быть внимательнее.